# How to edit animated object in powerpoint 2010

Tags: animation, microsoft-powerpoint

I have written some information in a slide. After that I have added many animations( picture, table) on top of information which I have written previously. Now I want to modify these information. Please suggest me how to do that in powerpoint 2010.

Comment: Modifying information in a slide is a software question, not a design question, and more appropriate for SuperUser.com.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Slideshow > Animations to customize your objects.